# Bash extract lines from paragraph

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a bash variable with multiline text inside it.

```
$ TEXT=$(cat<<-EOTEXT                   
line1                
line2                
======                 
line3
line4
======
EOTEXT)

$ echo  "$TEXT"
line1
line2
======
line3
line4
======
```

How do I extract a text between `=====`? The desired output is:

```
line3
line4
```

Please note that the line could be from 3 to 4000, so it should not be line specific.

Comment: Are the trailing spaces intended?

Comment: The example wouldn't work, by the way, `EOTEXT` must be on a line on its own, so `)` has to go on the next line.